# How to not return object values which are null with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot endpoint that returns a list of users. The users are populated into a DTO called `User`, however, some attributes of the user can be empty. Therefore how can I not send the empty attributes to the frontend?

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", produces = {"application/json"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getAllUsers() throws IOException {
        return kcAdminClient.getAllUsers();
    }
```

```java
public class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String contactNumber;
    private String address;
    private String[] roles;
}
```

```
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        int count = usersResource.count();
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<UserRepresentation> userRepresentationList = usersResource.list();;
        for (UserRepresentation ur : userRepresentationList) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setEmail(ur.getEmail());
            user.setFirstName(ur.getFirstName());
            user.setLastName(ur.getLastName());
            userList.add(user);
        }
        return userList;
    }
```

Returned values

```json
{
        "firstName": "test",
        "lastName": "test",
        "password": null,
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "contactNumber": null,
        "address": null,
        "roles": [
            "test"
        ]
    }
```

How can I stop the password and roles attribute from being sent as null?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` at the class level so your code would be like below,

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;

@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class User {
      private String firstName;
      private String lastName;
      private String password;
      private String email;
      private String contactNumber;
      private String address;
      private String[] roles;
}
```

This will ignore `null` values. For more info please visit [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields).

Answer (score 1):

Beside @Saurabh answer, and if you want to apply this behaviour globally across your application you can simply add this to your `application.properties` :

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion = non_null
```

For more objectMapper tunning you can check [Spring Boot Documentation > How To Customize The Jackson ObjectMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper)